# Regex to match a number followed by a specific string

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a number followed by a specific string, within another string.

The initial string could be:
some text 0.25mcg some more text
some text 25mcg some more text

so the number could be a decimal. I need to be able to return the number (so 0.25 or 25) where ever the number is followed by 'mcg'

Can anyone help me out. This doesn't work:

```
if(preg_match('(\d+mcg)', $item, $match))
```

Comment: the `\d` modifier will only match whole number ( 1,2,3... ) . that's why you are not matching  `0.25`. It does that because it's matching the actual caracter. In your case, you are telling it to match one or more digit caracter. At some point, the regex is finding a dot ( `. ` ) character so it does not match.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to capture a digit with an optional decimal part `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` and use a word boundary `\b` to prevent the match being part of a larger word.

```
\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)mcg\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhIMzc/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/XnLZD)

Code example

```
$re = '/\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)mcg\b/';
$str = 'some text 0.25mcg some more text some text 25mcg some more text';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.25
    [1] => 25
)
```

If you want a match only instead of a capturing group you might also opt for a positive lookahead `(?=` instead.

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=mcg\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tTlUjY/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/cJZ00)

Answer (score 0):

It's a job for [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all)

```
preg_match_all('/([\d.]+)mcg/', $item, $matches);
```

`[\d.]+` matches 1 or more digits or dot.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple version:

```
<?php
$item1 = 'some text 0.25mcg some more text';
$item2 = 'some text 25mcg some more text';

if (preg_match('/([0-9\\.]+)\\s*mcg/', $item1, $match)) echo $match[1] . '<br>';
if (preg_match('/([0-9\\.]+)\\s*mcg/', $item2, $match)) echo $match[1] . '<br>';
```